# How to vertically align text withing its line? (vertical-align is not working)

Tags: html, css

Here is the example of what I'm talking about, you need to zoom-in to see the problem 
[http://jsfiddle.net/54NEa/](http://jsfiddle.net/54NEa/1/)

```
<div id="top">SomeText</div>
<div id="middle">SomeText</div>
<div id="bottom">SomeText</div>

div{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode,Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
}
div.top {vertical-align:top;}
div.middle {vertical-align:middle;}
div.bottom {vertical-align:bottom}
```

the line is 10px, but text doesn't fill it completely, it has extra padding - in FF the padding is below and in Chrome its above, regardless of vertical-align property. This varies somewhat with font, but it never really fills its line-height completely, it "wiggles". Any ideas how to fix that font in one position relative to its line regardless of browsers? Im making a small css button and I need to make sure my line is exactly 10px in height and the text is also precisely 10px in height, so it always look the same.

Comment: have a look at this http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You must adjust line height to fit the element.

HTML:

```
    <div id="top"><span>SomeText</span></div>

div{
    height:30px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    font: 10px Lucida Sans Unicode,Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

span{
    line-height:30px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle:
[http://jsfiddle.net/54NEa/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/54NEa/3/)

Comment: The sample code is slightly confusing the way you've written it.

Comment: font: 10px/10px is the shortcut for font-size and line-height. Sorry, i added the full code

Comment: Im not sure if that fixes the problem... In a div with large height 1 or 2 pixels of padding are not very visible, and if I make the divs 10px in height, the padding is still there. Could you adjust your fiddle to make it small?

Comment: right, but the text still isn't aligned to either top or bottom

Comment: Yes. I used line height to align to center. You can use padding for the other two. Or put them in <table> the use valign

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` only applies to inline elements.  Try using a `span` instead of a `div`, or set `display:inline` on your divs.

**EDIT**

You also need to set the `font-size` and `line-height` of the container.  In this case, I used the body.  I also changed the display to `inline`, since you don't seem to need `inline-block`, and used unitless `line-height`

http://jsfiddle.net/78fxj/

Comment: Also, the preferred method for setting `line-height` is using a unitless value (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/line-height)

Comment: Did you try it? Setting display:inline made the line bigger, but vertical-align still doesn't work. Setting line-height: 100% also didn't do anything

Comment: I guess I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish...  sorry

Comment: OH!!!  I know what the problem is.... (well, I think I know)   The space between the `div`s does not have the style applied.  Put them all on the same line without any line breaks in between.

Comment: See my updated answer...  had to set the `font-size` and `line-height` of the container

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the div's display to table-cell. It's a pretty good solution, but sometimes it has other implications.

```
<div id="top">SomeText</div>
<div id="middle">SomeText</div>
<div id="bottom">SomeText</div>

div{
    display: **table-cell**;
    background-color: red;
    font: 10px/10px Lucida Sans Unicode,Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
div.top {vertical-align:top;}
div.middle {vertical-align:middle;}
div.bottom {vertical-align:bottom}
```